# Trying to delete the value of key for web application through firebase

Tags: javascript

what would make this work so that when the user types the correct tobedeleted value, the database deletes corresponding key with entered name?

```
function remove(){
var nameInput=document.getElementById("nameInput");
var database = firebase.database();
var tobedeleted = document.getElementById("tobedeleted").value;
var rootRef = database.ref("information");
var query = rootRef.orderByKey();

//gets generated keys
    query.once("value",function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        var val = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(val.name);
    console.log(tobedeleted);
    if (val.name===tobedeleted /*edited from val.name.equalTo(tobedeleted)*/) 
 {
        rootRef.child("information/"+key).remove();
    }
    });
});
```

Found the solution: just changed ("information/"+key) to (key)

Comment: Replace `val.name.equalTo(tobedeleted)` with `val.name===tobedeleted`

Comment: There is no `.equalTo(...)` method in javascript, it's got nothing to do with Firebase.

Comment: Since you merged two problems in one question, now the answer your wrote doesn't match the question at all. That's misleading.

Comment: @SnowGroomer sorry, I hadn't realized at the time that there were two problems. It wasn't intentional, and I'll change the post to reflect on changes. Thank you